# Can I set <iframe> src to session.getParameter("sub")

Tags: java, iframe

I was trying to set  src with session.getParameter("sub") but this is not working , can anyone please guide me through this ? (please refer following code:-)

```
<iframe src="./views/study/" +<%=session.getAttribute("sub")%> 
                                                  id="frame1" seamless></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the following

`<iframe src='./views/study/<%=session.getAttribute("sub")%>' id="frame1" seamless>  </iframe>`

Comment: Actually after asking this question to my friend, he told me the same . By the way thanks for your time and early response.